# Python how to decrypting a text when there is no biunivocal relation of conversion?

Tags: python, math, encryption, cryptography

With the included Python batteries it is possible to write a code to encrypt and decrypt by substitution (as in cipher):

```
def cifrar(word, BASE, CIFRA_CODE):
    table = str.maketrans(BASE, CIFRA_CODE)
    return print(word.translate(table))

def decifar(word, BASE, CIFRA_CODE):
    table = str.maketrans(CIFRA_CODE, BASE)
    return print(word.translate(table))

def main():
    BASE = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    CIFRA_CODE = "DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC"
    menu = int(input("(1) Crypto (2) Decrypt: "))
    word = input("Enter the word: ").upper()

    if menu == 1:
        cifrar(word, BASE, CIFRA_CODE)
    elif menu == 2:
        decifar(word, BASE, CIFRA_CODE)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

In the case there is a biunivocal relation. Each letter corresponds to just another letter.

But how to generate all the possibilities of decrypting a text when there is no biunivocal relation of conversion? For example, the cipher character G may correspond to either the original A, D, F or Z characters, and the M character may correspond to H and Z.

```
 BASE =       "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
 CIFRA_CODE = "GEFGHGJMLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABM"
```

Comment: If there is no biunivocal  relation, how is this cipher decoded at all? Obviously there are stateful ciphers so that output depends on all the previous input (characters) but this doesn't seem to be what you describe. So how does your **_algorithm_** work? Without clear specification it is impossible to write the code. To put it otherwise, typical cipher works such that someone who knows both algorithm and the "secret" (aka "key") can decipher the single (correct) message. How this is supposed to work in this case?

Comment: I would say this is more of a crypto.stackexchange.com question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because in my opinion it belongs to crypto.stackexchange.com

Comment: @d33tah Unfortunately the closing of crypto questions is almost completely FUBAR. But it is the only thing we can do.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution:

```
def key_to_map(key):
m = {}
alphabet = list("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ")
while(key):
    k = key.pop()
    m[k] = [alphabet.pop()] + m.get(k, [])
return m

def decrypt(ciphertext, key_map, plaintext):
    if not ciphertext:
        yield plaintext
    else:
        current = ciphertext[0]
        for possibility in key_map.get(current, [current]):
            for plain in decrypt(ciphertext[1: ], key_map, plaintext + possibility):
                yield plain

def main():
ciphertext = input("Entre com o texto cifrado: ").upper()
key = list("DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC")
key_map = key_to_map(key)
result = list(decrypt(ciphertext, key_map, ""))
print("Resultados Possíveis: ")
print(result)
for x in result:
    print(x)
print("Quantidade de Hipóteses Possíveis: {}".format(len(result)))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Thanks all